# Parallel hashing using openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, hashtable, openmp, hpc

I have a piece of code for parallel hashing, the insert code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
     .....
    Entry* table;//hash table
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++){
       keys[i]=i;
       values[i] = rand();//random key-value pairs
    }
    int omp_p = omp_get_max_threads();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int p=0;p<omp_p;p++){
       size_t start = p*N/omp_p;
       size_t end = (p+1)*N/omp_p;//each thread gets contiguous chunks of the arrays
       for(size_t i=start;i<end;i++){
          size_t key = keys[i];
          size_t value = values[i];
          if(insert(table,key,value) == 0){
             printf("Failure!\n");
          }
       }
    }
    ....
    return 0;
}

int insert(Entry* table,size_t key, size_t value){
   Entry entry = (((Entry)key) << 32)+value; //Coalesce key and value into an entry
   /*Use cuckoo hashing*/
   size_t location = hash_function_1(key);

   for(size_t its=0;its<MAX_ITERATIONS;its++){
       entry = __sync_lock_test_and_set(&table[location],entry);
       key=get_key(entry);
       if(key == KEY_EMPTY)
          return1;
       }
       /*We have replaced a valid key, try to hash it using next available hash function*/
       size_t location_1 = hash_function_1(key);
       size_t location_2 = hash_function_2(key);
       size_t location_3 = hash_function_3(key);
       if(location == location_1) location = location_2;
       else if(location == location_2) location = location_3;
       else                            location = location_1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The insert code doesn't scale at all. If I use a single thread, for say, 10M keys, I complete in about 170ms, whereas using 16 threads, I take > 500ms. My suspicion is that this is because the cache line (consisting of the table[] array) is being moved around between the threads during the write operation (__sync_lock_test_and_set(...)) and the invalidation results in a slow down 
For example if I modify the insert code to just:

```
int insert(Entry* table,size_t key, size_t value){
   Entry entry = (((Entry)key) << 32)+value; //Coalesce key and value into an entry

   size_t location = hash_function_1(key);
   table[location] = entry;
   return 1;
}
```

I still get the same bad performance. Since this is hashing, I cannot control, where a particular element hashes to. So any suggestions? Also, if this isn't the right reason, any other pointers as to what might be going wrong? I have tried it from 1M to 100M keys, but the single threaded performance is always better.

Comment: Is there any reason to manually assign the chunk to threads (instead having OpenMP doing it)?

Comment: i get slightly better results though single core performance still hits me bad

Comment: I don't get why... You are dividing an array like `static` would do. Further, the array is read-only in the multi-threaded part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions.  Since the run time of your `insert` function is not constant then you should use `schedule(dynamic)`.  Second, you should let OpenMP divide the tasks and not do it yourself (one reason, but not the main reason, is that the way you have it now `N` has to be a multiple of `omp_p`).  If you want to have some control over how it divides the tasks then try changing the chunksize like this `schedule(dynamic,n)` where n is the chuck size.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++){
    size_t key = keys[i];
    size_t value = values[i];
    if(insert(table,key,value) == 0){
       printf("Failure!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help. The insert procedure is still bad. I don't need to worry about omp_p not being a multiple of N since that is in my hands.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part about the insert procedure not working.  Maybe you have a race condition.  For example at "table[location] = entry;" or "entry = __sync_lock_test_and_set(&table[location],entry);"  If different values of key, value, entry produce the same location I think that would give a race condition.  Have you tried putting these in a critical section?

Comment: No, the insert procedure is working correctly. When I mean, its bad, I mean the performance is bad i.e. it isn't scaling with the number of cores, probably due to false and/or true sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try experimenting with a strategy based on locks, like this simple snippet shows:

```
#include<omp.h>

#define NHASHES 4
#define NTABLE  1000000
typedef size_t (hash_f)(size_t);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Entry      table [NTABLE ]; 
  hash_f     hashes[NHASHES];
  omp_lock_t locks [NTABLE ]
  /* ... */
  for(size_t ii = 0; ii < N; ii++) {
    keys    [ii] = ii;
    values  [ii] = rand();
  }
  for(size_t ii = 0; ii < NTABLE; ii++) {
    omp_init_lock(&locks[ii]);
  }
#pragma omp parallel
  {
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for(int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++) {

    size_t key   = keys  [ii];
    size_t value = values[ii];
    Entry  entry = (((Entry)key) << 32) + value;

    for ( jj = 0; jj < NHASHES; jj++ ) {
      size_t location = hashes[jj];   // I assume this is the computationally demanding part
      omp_set_lock(&locks[location]); // Locks the hash table location before working on it
      if ( get_key(table[location]) == KEY_EMPTY ) {
        table[location] = entry;
        break;
      }
      omp_unset_lock(&locks[location]); // Unlocks the hash table location
    }
    // Handle failures here
    }
  } /* pragma omp parallel */
  for(size_t ii = 0; ii < NTABLE; ii++) {
    omp_destroy_lock(&locks[ii]);
  }
  /* ... */
  return 0;
}
```

With a little more machinery you can handle a variable number of locks ranging from `1`  (equivalent to a `critical` section) to `NTABLE` (equivalent to an `atomic` construct) and see if the granularity in-between provides some benefit.

Comment: Wouldn't adding locks just slow down the code? For example, see the second "insert" code snippet I posted where I don't care if threads clobber each other's entries. i.e "table[location]=entry". This doesn't require any synchronization and is embarrassingly parallel but it is still not scalable.